# An error occurs when I start my system

Tags: package-management, permissions, startup, software-sources, messaging-menu

How can I locate this error in Ubuntu, what can be due, how can I repair it?

I try to follow this post [PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure) for the solution of the problem but I do not have success.

This is the warning message:

1

[image]

2

[image]

I have located two files in `/var/crash/` and I deleted them with command `sudo rm /var/crash/*`but before I made a copy.

The image number one no longer I see but the second still persists.

No more files are generated in `/var/crash/`

In the `/var/log/syslog` directory repeatedly the following error message:

> E: Opening /etc/apt/sources.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
>
> E: The list of sources could not be read.
>
> E: Opening /etc/apt/sources.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
>
> E: The list of sources could not be read.

The output of entering the command `sudo apt update`

[image]

The output of entering the command `sudo apt upgrade`

[image]

The output of entering the command `sudo apt-get -f install`

[image]

The warning indicator persists after running `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Removing the packages list and updating does not solve this for me.
I have also followed these steps:

Open the terminal: `Ctrl+Alt+T`

Remove the package list:

`sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

```
-v, --verbose explain what is being done

-f, --force ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

Update the packages:

`sudo apt-get update`

Something else that I have also done:

```
ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Appeared:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 747 ene 17 20:26 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In a post I read that creating a new `source.list` would solve the problem, in my case it has not been so

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.old | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I noticed your sources.list do not have read permission for Other, perhaps that may be causing the permission denied error? Do try `sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list` and let me know if it works.

My sources.list: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2968 Jan 16 23:50 /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: YES it has been solved, I am very happy to have solved this problem, thanks for your answer, I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The message means that at some point, in this session or in previous ones, there has been a system error, it has been registered in a "log" and it is pending to send the Ubuntu developers to review it. The warning message is only to ask you permission to send it and that you can review it and fix it in future updates (or not send it).

If you want to get rid of these messages that come out every time you restart your machine, just open a terminal and do:

```
$ sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

... which will delete these pending logs to send.

Of course, if your machine continues to generate errors of this type, these logs will continue to be generated, and so the same messages will come back to you again and again.

With respect to the second warning message I am still trying to solve it.